# Parasitic values of a laminated core inductor

Tags: inductor

How do I determine the parasitic values of an inductor? Since an inductor is made up of a series resistor with the inductor and a parasitic capacitor(parallel capacitor between turns and the core).
My challenge is how to determine the capacitor between turns, capacitor between the turn and the core.

Comment: Build it and measure.  Calculation or simulation isn't going to give you a realistic answer.

Comment: Why are you concerned with the parasitic capacitance of the laminated core inductor. It can’t be expected to run at a particularly high frequency due to the laminations and eddy currents.

Comment: @Andyaka  eddy currents scale wilth volts/turn, frequency has no effect.

Comment: @Jasen then why bother with laminations at all and why are ferries non conducting?

Comment: like I said volts per turn

Comment: @Andyaka Ferrites are nonconductive because they aren't metals. I'm not sure what the confusion is there.

Comment: @Andyaka volts per turn is increased to put more power through the transformer, frequency is increased to avoid core saturation

Comment: @Jasen - what has saturation got to do with eddy currents in the core? Do you understand what you are saying?

Comment: @Hearth the point I'm making is that with a laminated core, the upper frequency at which an inductor can reasonably perform is limited by excessive induction into the conducting laminates. That is why we use ferrite cores for higher frequencies because they are basically non-conducting up to a much higher frequency and therefore do not suffer from eddy current losses. You don't need to get involved; the OP should justify why he is interested in the winding capacitance of a component that cannot be run at high frequencies.

Comment: @Andyaka   saturation is the reason for frequency frequency allows volts per turn, volts per turn causes eddy currents

Answer (score 1):

For a layer-wound coil, the self capacitance is dominated by the layer to layer capacitance, compared to which the turn to turn capacitance is negligible. This is good enough for a ball-park calculation.